# Showing datetime in two td tags

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to show datetime field separately. Using `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DateField,101) as DatePart` gives me errors.

This is my original code:

```
$sql = "SELECT product.name, orders.date, orders.time FROM orders INNER JOIN 
product ON orders.product_id = product.id AND 
orders.customer_id='$customer_id'";
```

First, I've changed my orders table date and time to just datetime, and now I want to show them separately. As it was working before.

Secondly, Is my join correct? I want to know what customer has bought so far?

Comment: Please share the error that you were getting and the original code that gave error too

Comment: Also the table structure and the value in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TIME](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time-function.php) and [DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp) functions. For your `JOIN`, the customer_id check should be in the `Where` because it's not linked to product. Furthermore, if you have two columns in different tables, you should always put the name of the table before so the program will know what column you are talking about (see here `product.product_id`).

```
SELECT product.name, DATE(orders._datetime), TIME(orders._datetime) 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN product ON orders.product_id = product.product.id 
WHERE orders.customer_id='$customer_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-11-13 11:10:09', '%Y-%m-%d') AS date, 
       DATE_FORMAT('2017-11-13 11:10:09', '%T') AS time;
```

Output is

```
date        time
2017-11-13  11:10:09
```

Your join looks ok to me.